Как сделать чтобы мой дискорд бот мог общаться с пользователями?
Как сделать чтобы дискорд бот мог общаться с пользователем?
Например: если пользователь напишет Саня привет, то дискорд бот должен ответить пользователю любыми ответами.
Пример:
Пользователь: Саня привет(или просто можно написать "Привет" без "Саня")
Бот: Привет(ответы на сообщение "Привет" должны быть разные ответы)
Пользователь: Привет(можно выбрать и другие варианты ответа, например: "Здравствуйте", "Приветульки", "Здрасте" и так далее)
Бот: Привет(дискорд бот должен отвечать пользователю по-разному)
Пользователь: Пока(можно выбрать и другие варианты ответа, например: "До встречи", "Пока-пока", "Ещё увидимся")
Как такое можно сделать для дискорд бота на библиотеке disnake в версии библиотеки disnake 2.9.1 на языке программировании python? Можно ли сделать так чтобы ответы дискорд бота отправлялись из файла answers.json? А если бот не нашёл что ответить пользователю, то дискорд бот должен поставить реакцию "❓" на сообщение пользователя если дискорд бот не нашёл что ответить пользователю

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Я хочу чтобы мой дискорд бот мог отправлять сообщения пользователю. Пример должен быть такой:
Пользователь: Привет
Бот: Привет(дискорд бот должен отвечать пользователю по-разному) а если бот не нашёл что ответить пользователю, то дискорд бот ставит реакцию "❓" на сообщение пользователя если дискорд бот не нашёл что ответить пользователю

Либо подключить ИИ, либо написать кучу if'ов, которые будут проверить содержимое сообщение и на основе этого отправлять заготовленный ответ.
